# when I split a string into multiple strings, how do I get a certain part of that string?

Tags: java

I am trying to find a way to have access to a specific string after a bigger string is broken down into smaller strings. Below is an example:
So now that there are two strings, how do I get the first or second? Since there are brackets, I thought that it is an array of string so I thought all I had to do was do something like System.out.println(parts[0]); But that doesnt work..

```
String string = "hello ::= good morning";
String parts = Arrays.toString(string.split("::="));
System.out.println(parts);
```

the output should be [hello, good morning]

Answer (score 3):

You need to put it an array like so:

```
String s = "I Like Apples."    
String[] parts = s.split(" ");

for(String a : parts)
 System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: Anytime. You can even get more advanced down the road with regex splitting. Here's a reference for regex if you need it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 2):

It works fine if you just remove `Arrays.toString(...`:

```
String string = "hello ::= good morning";
String parts[] = string.split("::=");
System.out.println(parts[0]);
```

Update:

To print the whole array, you can do this:-

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Also, to trim the spaces, you can change the split line to:-

```
String parts[] = string.trim().split("\\s*::=\\s*");
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a better use case for pattern grouping with a *regular expression* to me. I would group the left-hand side and right-hand side of `::=` preceded and followed by optional white-space. For example,

```
String string = "hello ::= good morning";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+)\\s*::=\\s*(.+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

Which outputs

```
good morning
```

If you also wanted "hello" that would be `m.group(1)`